# How can I stop image's onloading when it's loading

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I was using CORS to load image from Google Map which can be used as texture in my webGL application... Sometimes I want to stop the image's transmission because I want to delete the texture... Now I just delete the image texture in **image.onload()** function to make my idea works. Can I just stop the transmission so that the javascript will **not run to onload**... And how can I use javascript to **stop the image's transmission** during loading? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop an image while it's loading you can erase the url attribute. If it's still loading, it will never get to onLoad.

> document.getElementById("id").src=""

Comment: my image is load by var obj=new image(); obj.onload=function{}; obj.src="xxx"; Does your method work?

Comment: Yes: just stop the transfer with `obj.src=""`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the detachEvent method:-

```
window.detachEvent("load", fn)
```

where fn is the function that was attached, however since there is jquery in this mix it may be a tall order getting hold of the actual function that was attached. Most likely the actual function attached will be anonymous.

or you can try

```
$(window).unbind("load")
```